# Merge, and its result in R

Tags: r, merge, stata

I want to merge datasets in R, but I want to know which row succeeded to merge after the merge process.
In Stata, `_merge` column is generated automatically after the merge process, and the column has 3 values, `master only(1), using only(2), and matched(3)`, respectively. [You can see the output screenshot here.](https://www.reddit.com/r/stata/comments/q5wn64/when_i_merge_my_two_stata_sets_using_country_the/)

I think R also has this function, but it is hard to search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add columns that allow the source to be identified

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=c("a","b","c"), y=c(1,2,3))
df2 <- data.frame(x=c("a","b","d"), z=c(1,2,NA))

# solution:
df1$in1 <- TRUE
df2$in2 <- TRUE
merge(df1, df2, all=TRUE)
```

To add the labels as your example

```
df3$source <- ifelse(df3$in1 & is.na(df3$in2), "master only", 
                     ifelse(df3$in2 & is.na(df3$in1), "using only", "matched"))
df3$in1 <- NULL
df3$in2 <- NULL
```

Comment: Thank you. Additionally, I want to add some code : `df %>% mutate(merge=ifelse(in1 == TRUE & in2 == NA, "master only", ifelse(in1 == NA & in2 == TRUE, "using only", "matched"))))` But it cannot work smoothly.

Comment: use `is.na()` instead of the `... == NA` - see updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much...!!! :D Your answer is perfect for me.